# how to Clear or replace contents of input field using selenium?

Tags: ruby, selenium

How can i clear the contents of an input field using ruby selenium?

i.e when page loads up there are values in the input filed but i want to replace them with new ones.

thank you

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732125/clear-text-from-textarea-with-selenium for another answer (using .clear())

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Come on guys... You can't be serious...

With selenium to clear an input field do this: selenium.type("") in ruby too.

And backspacing as many times as there are letters... Come on.. you don't do stuff like that.

Or in Ruby syntax: @browser.type "idofthefield", ""

Comment: thanks, I thought that selenium.type("") would just add nothing to the input already there. thanks

Comment: The proper function is called `clear()`. You can't be serious ... readthedocs please.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i cleared and replaced with new text in my Ruby based web portal test

```
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//input[@name='ip-address']").clear
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//input[@name='ip-address']").send_keys(new_ip_address)
```

Comment: This is the way to "clear" a field. Im glad you use .clear with no () function call ...