# How can I clear a text box field for safaridriver using webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, textfield, safaridriver

How can I clear a text box field for safaridriver using webdriver?

I used this below command which only works for chrome and Firefox but does not work for safari.

driver.findElement(By.id("userEmail")).clear();

Comment: Seems like a simple Javascript call ought to work, if Safari somehow dislikes WebDriver.  What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: i'm getting below error.                                                                     org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element does not exist in cache (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Sounds like the element doesn't exist in the cache.   I don't know enough about webdriver to know why; perhaps you added the element dynamically (using Javascript), without telling webdriver about it?

Comment: It works for Firefox and Chrome but does not work for safari

Comment: Yes, I know.  You said that already in your question.  Since it's a caching problem, you might want to examine how the "cache" is behaving.

Answer (score -1):

Clear the element using

```
function name()
{  
document.getElementById('elementid').value = "";
}
```

Comment: I am new to Webdriver, i don't know what to do with this code

Comment: Are you using [Selenium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/)?

Comment: You can refer to this question [Clear text from textarea with selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732125/clear-text-from-textarea-with-selenium)