# Clearing a html input box using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to clear an input on indeed but the clear() function is not working. Any ideas on how to clear the input box?

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.indeed.com")
#this is not clearning the input
elem2 = driver.find_element_by_id("text-input-where").clear()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using waits thats also an issue.

So use wait first and as @Sers stated use JavaScript executor

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.indeed.com")

    WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'text-input-where')))

    elem2 = driver.find_element_by_id("text-input-where")

    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value = "";', elem2)
```

Below Java code working for me:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.indeed.com");
WebDriverWait waiter = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
waiter.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("text-input-where")));
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("text-input-where"));

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value ='';", element);
```

Answer (score 9):

First thing i'd like to point out is you are using

> elem2 = driver.find_element_by_id("text-input-where").clear()

clear() – clear the value of any text type element. It doesn’t allow any parameter and its return type is **void**. So `elem2` will be null.

Second, we can use a combination of methods depending upon the application under test.

Sometimes, `driver.find_element_by_id("text-input-where").clear()` doesn't work, if element is not clicked first. So we can do,

```
driver.find_element_by_id("text-input-where").click();
driver.find_element_by_id("text-input-where").clear();
driver.find_element_by_id("text-input-where").sendKeys(textContent);
```

OR we can also use Actions class and Webdriver waits.

```
elem2 = WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'text-input-where')))
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elem2).click(elem2).perform()
elem2.clear();
```

OR as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732125/clear-text-from-textarea-with-selenium), we can simulate CTRL + A and DEL keys.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("text-input-where").click();
driver.find_element_by_id("text-input-where").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
driver.find_element_by_id("text-input-where").send_keys(Keys.DELETE);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try sending backspace keys:

```
def clear_text(element):
    length = len(element.get_attribute('value'))
    element.send_keys(length * Keys.BACKSPACE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript to set value to empty string:

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value = "";', driver.find_element_by_id("text-input-where"))
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work for all systems:

```py
from sys import platform
def clear(elem):
  elem.send_keys((Keys.COMMAND if platform == "darwin" else Keys.CONTROL) + "a")
  elem.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
clear(driver.find_element((By.ID, "id")))
```

Call the function and pass the webelement as an argument