# Incorrect password string gets entered by send_keys in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Somehow **send_keys** enters repeat password or string other than mentioned password leading login failure. 
Tried adding explicit wait(), driver.clear() but does not work.
Here is a sample code in Python -

**Approach 1 -**

```
driver = webdriver.chrome(executable path)
driver.maximize__window()
driver.get(address)

password = "xyz"
field1 = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, <xpath of the password field>)
actionChains.move_to_element(field1).click()
actionChains.move_to_element(field1).send_keys(password).perform()

driver.find_element(By.ID, "Login-button").click()
```

Here instead of "xyz" probably "xyzxyzxyzx" string gets added to the password field(cannot decode as password gets masked).

Please suggest.

**Approach 2** -

Also, another try with below code somehow concatenates username to the password while entering password.

```
username = driver.find_element(By.ID,"USERNAME").click()
actionChains.send_keys("test")

password = driver.find_element(By.ID,"PASSWORD").click()
actionChains.send_keys("xyz")

actionChains.perform()
```

This snippet results into -

Username as "test" 
Password as "testxyz"

Expected output is:

Username as "test" 
Password as "xyz"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it auto fills the last input. I get around it by just adding "Keys.BACK_SPACE*20" into the send keys brackets

```
.send_keys(Keys.BACK_SPACE*20, "xyz")
```

you will also need to import the Keys library:

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

Comment: Just perfect. I was using keys.DELETE but was not helping much.

Answer (score 0):

Some assumptions that come to the top of my mind are some default values may have been populated already in the password field. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732125/clear-text-from-textarea-with-selenium) may be helpful if that's the scenario. I'm not sure if that's the same thing driver.clear() does.

Also if there's a show password option that can be utilised to debug the issue. also other options for those can be gettext from the text box also can be helpful.