# Selenium Python clear() method not working

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to clear the value of an input HTML element using the selenium clear() method, but it is not working as expected, so the send_keys() method appends the new value to the current value of the input box.

Here is my code:

```py
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service as EdgeService
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options as EdgeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

service = EdgeService(executable_path="path/to/edge_driver.exe")
options = EdgeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service, options=options)

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login")

username = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username")))
username.clear()
username.send_keys("Admin")

password = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password")))
password.clear()
password.send_keys("admin123")

login_xpath = "//*[@id='app']/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[3]/button"
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, login_xpath))).click()

admin_xpath = "//*[@id='app']/div[1]/div[1]/aside/nav/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a"
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, admin_xpath))).click()

edit_xpath = "//*[@id='app']/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/div/button[2]"
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, edit_xpath))).click()

name_xpath = "//*[@id='app']/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/input"
name = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, name_xpath)))
name.clear()
sleep(10)
name.send_keys("Dummy Text")
```

Link to the public-facing site which I used to reproduce the problem: - OrangeHRM(orangehrmlive.com)

What I've tried:

1. `element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')` with `element.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)` or `element.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)`
2. `driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value = ''`, `driver.find_element_by_id("text-input-where"))`

Only `Keys.BACKSPACE` is working but to clear all text I have to use the loop which I don't want to.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Have a look at this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27799120/3559908) on a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

As one of workarounds for such cases, you can focus input and click backspaces several times (that equal input value length).

This is not perfect solution, however, it simulates user behaviour:

```py
name = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, name_xpath)))
name.click()
value = name.get_property('value')
for i in range(len(value)):
    name.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
```